# PHP script not creating JSON file correctly

Tags: c#, php, json

So I hav e a C# application which creates files and saves data through a php script. The JSON data gets encoded with base64 before the application sends it to the PHP script. The PHP script then decodes it and writes it to a JSON file and saves it to the JSON folder in the public_html folder. Then the PHP script reads the data from the JSON file and sends it to the mysql server. But this doesn't work yet.

Here is my full PHP script:

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='username';
$pass='userpass';
$db='database';

$link = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if($link ->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Database connection wrong<br/>';
}
else {
    echo 'Database connection OK<br/>';
    $jsonstring = base64_decode($_POST['b64string']);
    $filename = $_POST['filename'] . '.json';

    $create = fopen(__DIR__. "/json/" . $filename, "W+");
    fwrite($create, $jsonstring);

    $json = fread($create, filesize(__DIR__. "/json/" . $filename));
    fclose($create);

    $obj = json_decode($json);

    $query_opslaan = "INSERT INTO database (BedrijfsNaam, ContPers, TelNr, Email, Land, Plaats, POC) VALUES ('". $obj->bedrijfsNaam ."' , '". $obj->ContPers ."', '". $obj->TelNum ."', '". $obj->email ."', '". $obj->Land ."', '". $obj->Plaats ."', '". $obj->PostCode ."')";



    mysqli_query($link, $query_opslaan) or die(mysqli_error($query_opslaan));

    delete(__DIR__."/json/".$filename);
}
?>
```

and this C# script sends the data:

```
json = "{\"bedrijfsNaam\":\"" + bedrijfsNaam + "\"," +
"\"ContPers\":\"" + ContPers + "\"," +
"\"TelNum\":\"" + TelNum + "\"," +
"\"email\":\"" + email + "\"," +
"\"Land\":\"" + Land + "\"," +
"\"Plaats\":\"" + Plaats + "\"," +
"\"PostCode\":\"" + PostCode + "\"}";

var b64bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
b64encode = System.Convert.ToBase64String(b64bytes);

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] sendB64 = client.UploadData("http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scripturi"].ToString() + "SalesKicker.php", "POST",
                System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("b64string=" + b64encode + "&filename=" + dt.bedrijfsNaam));
}
```

The problem is that when the PHP tries to save the data it saves blank data because the JSON file was never created.
This is my first try at this and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So what's the value of `$jsonString`? And what specifically isn't working?

Comment: the $jsonString has the same value as the json string in my C# script. for the problem read the last part of my question

Comment: Okay, next question, why are you creating a file, writing to it, reading it and then deleting it? Why bother? What's wrong with $json = json_decode($jsonString);`?